# How to run Mocha Test in silent mode in terminal

Tags: linux, bash, testing, terminal, mocha.js

I have to run multiple times the mocha test with different inputs.

I dont like to wait for the result like

> mocha test

will output

> Test Mocha
>
> ```
> ✓ IT Test 
>
> ✓ login with  account  (719ms)
> ```
>
> 2 passing (3s)

I like to run in silent mode like

> mocha test
>
> test started

and I can run other test and I don't care for output result 
Im running linux so whatever idea would be great :)

Answer (score 5):

You have to use a custom reporter to filter all the results you do not want to see.

Crawling `npm` I found the [`mocha-silent-reporter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-silent-reporter) which seems to fit what you are looking for.

It basically filters everything except failures (which are always useful).

## Update

I completely missed in the first place that `mocha` has his own minimalistic reporter that does what you are looking for.

```
$ mocha --reporter min test

✔ N tests complete (X ms)
```

I've tested the `mocha-silent-reporter` and I had some issues with that. I'd rather recommend to try to use the built-in reporter in mocha.